# Page becomes unscrollable after uBlock blocking an overlay

Tags: youtube, css, browser-addons

I have the following filters defined to deal with Youtube's new annoying anti-adblock overlay.

```
! 2023-10-26 https://www.youtube.com
www.youtube.com##tp-yt-paper-dialog.ytd-popup-container.style-scope

! 2023-10-27 https://www.youtube.com
www.youtube.com##.opened
```

this successfuly hides the overlay. The first filter is the modal itself the second one the gray tint full page overlay and the mouse-wheel doesn't work.

However after the filter grips and removes the elements, the page becomes unscrollable. A scrollbar is visible but it can not be pulled.

Can I make uBlock hiding an element and allowing a page still being scrollable?

Comment: Please add more details like the name and version of the web browser that you are using. Remember that questions that might require too much back and forth (troubleshooting) are considered off-topic, so if you have not done so yet, consider creating a specific profile to use only with uBlock while you are trying to find the user style to avoid noise that might cause other extensions.